# Apache Tomcat Cluster: Shared Objects / Events / Messages / Singletons

Tags: tomcat, singleton, message, cluster-computing

I'm up to migrate an WebApplication into an Apache Tomcat Cluster.

I'm  now need to share some Events / Messages / Objects along the Cluster.
Eg. I got some critical long running Methods, that are only alowed to be started once in the whole Cluster.

Also there are some Events that should be shared. Like reload some Cached values.

Has someone some experience / best Practices /  Tutorials to share about this issue?

I also read some Information about Terracotta for the shared objects, or Apache Tribes for Multicast Messaging. Has anyone some experience with this Frameworks? Or some good starter Tutorials?

Are there better Frameworks available for the described tasks?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/). It is free, open source and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JGroups to do this. Sample implementation can be found at http://speakingjava.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-execute-singleton-task-in-cluster.html